# Can't override a method of parent class

Tags: java, overriding, ioexception

I get a compile error when trying to override method of a parent class:

```
public class Reader {
    public void readToDbFromFile(String fileName, String table) throws FileNotFoundException() {
         ....
    }
}

public class ReaderWithBackup extends Reader {
    @Override
    public void readToDbFromFile(String fileName, String table) throws IOException {
        super.readToDbFromFile();
        doBackup(fileName, table);
    }

    ...
}
```

It says 'overriden method does not throw IOException'. What does it mean? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: compare the two methods... both do throw different Exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overridden method throws `FileNotFoundException`, so the overriding method must throw `FileNotFoundException` or a sub-class of `FileNotFoundException`. `IOException` is a super-class of `FileNotFoundException`, so it can't be thrown by the overriding method.

Consider this code :

```
try {
    Reader reader = ...
    reader.readToDbFromFile(..);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ..
}
```

This is valid code, since `readToDbFromFile` method of `Reader` can only throw `FileNotFoundException` checked exceptions. If you override `readToDbFromFile` is some sub-class of `Reader`, this code must still be valid if you assign an instance of your sub-class to the `reader` variable. Therefore your overriding method can't throw an exception that is not covered by the throws clause of the original method.

Comment: IOException is a parent of FileNotFoundException, right? If parent method threw FileNotFoundException, why can't child generalize it?

Comment: @JohnBrownstone What if the child class decides to throw a `SocketException`. That's a sub-class of `IOException`. However, the parent method only declares that it throws `FileNotFoundException`, so the child method shouldn't be able to throw `SocketException`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot throw a `Parent Exception` of the super class method in  overridden method in child class.

As `FileNotFoundException` is an subclass of `IOException` you can not throw `IOException` in child class.

SO you can do like this by swapping `IOException` and  `FileNotFoundException` :-

```
public class Reader {
    public void readToDbFromFile(String fileName, String table) throws IOException () {
         ....
    }
}

public class ReaderWithBackup extends Reader {
    @Override
    public void readToDbFromFile(String fileName, String table) throws FileNotFoundException{
        super.readToDbFromFile();
        doBackup(fileName, table);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your parrent class `readToDbFromFile` throw `FileNotFoundException`. You should throw `FileNotFoundException` not `IOException` in your override function.